# Most complete source of international address formats?

Tags: street-address

I'm looking for a source that describes the standard address format for most of the world's countries. I've found sources for the more prominent Western and Asian countries, but these sources tend to peter out pretty quickly when you get away from larger/more influential countries.

Ideally I'd like to see something similar [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=PfJtoKj-VF4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_v2_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=&f=false) book, but more up-to-date, and not in dead-tree form. Does such a data source exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a couple of useful links:
http://www.usps.com/international/addressingintlmail.htm
http://pe.usps.gov/text/imm/immc1_007.htm

This site has TONS of country based information:
http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/postal.html

Also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_%28geography%29#Mailing_address_format_by_country

This companies services seem interesting and related also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_d%C2%B4adresse_mondial

UPU Standard:
http://www.upu.int/acts/en/2_letter_en.pdf

Comment: I'll add to that [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes) of postal code formats